# H2 not update my jsp web form to my simple database using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, h2

Why is my data from my web form not updated to my database, H2, Spring Boot

```
<body>
<form action = "addAlien">
<input type ="text" name="aid", value="123"><br>
<input type ="text" name="aname"><br>
<input type ="text" name="aship"><br>
<input type ="submit"><br>



</form>
```

emark3462@gmail.com

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying me yesterday, I am not really familiar with this site: but I really hope someone can help me with my project. I am in the US, so can we set a time may be tonight or tomorrow, you can look at my code on Skype or Teamview, I can better explain. I can pay you $20/Hour via Paypal or other methods. I have many other projects, we can make something happens. If you are OK, let me know a time and your Skype ID?

Comment: Is it possible to share the code in Git?

Comment: There are too many files, it always gives errors, that is why I want to do it on Skype. I added my email just under the code.